# Múltiplos COUNT() em uma unica consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
| idAcesso   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | auto_increment |
| dataAcesso | date         | NO   |     |                |
| contato    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+
```

O objetivo dela é saber quantas pessoas, das que acessaram uma determinada página, entraram em contato. Existem dois formulários de contato na página e, a coluna contato, recebe o ID do formulário utilizado ou o valor NULL caso não tenha entrado em contato.

Eu preciso retornar o total de linhas que foi feito contato ou não agrupado por dias. Mais ou menos isso:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| dataAcesso | totalAcessos | totalContatos | semContato |
+------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-09-28 |           98 |            98 |         98 |
| 2019-09-29 |          114 |           114 |        114 |
| 2019-09-30 |          197 |           197 |        197 |
| 2019-10-01 |          185 |           185 |        185 |
| 2019-10-02 |          163 |           163 |        163 |
| 2019-10-03 |          167 |           167 |        167 |
| 2019-10-04 |           93 |            93 |         93 |
| 2019-10-05 |          102 |           102 |        102 |
| 2019-10-06 |          154 |           154 |        154 |
| 2019-10-07 |          295 |           295 |        295 |
+------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

O problema é que esses valores não batem, os 3 totais tem valores diferentes e o totalAcessos deveria ser a soma dos outros totais.

Eu consigo pegar os valores corretos com 3 SQLs diferentes mas gostaria de saber se existe um modo de fazer essas consulta de maneira correta usando apenas uma consulta.

O que eu estou tentando:

```
SELECT
    dataAcesso,
    COUNT( idAcesso ) AS totalAcessos,
    COUNT( !ISNULL( contato ) ) AS totalContatos,
    COUNT( ISNULL( contato ) ) AS semContato
FROM
    acessos
GROUP BY
    dataAcesso
```

Alguma dica de como posso fazer essa consulta?

Obrigado.

---

### EDIT

Um exemplo de como as linhas podem estar preenchidas:

```
+----------+------------+---------+
| idAcesso | dataAcesso | contato |
+----------+------------+---------+
|        1 | 2019-09-28 |       1 |
|        2 | 2019-09-28 |       2 |
|        3 | 2019-09-28 |       2 |
|        4 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|        5 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|        6 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|        7 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|        8 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|        9 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       10 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       11 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       12 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       13 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       14 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       15 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       16 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       17 | 2019-09-28 |    NULL |
|       18 | 2019-09-28 |       1 |
|       19 | 2019-09-28 |       1 |
|       20 | 2019-09-28 |       1 |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

A resposta do Ricardo Pontual acabou me levando a solução, visto que eu não sabia que o COUNT não conta valores nulos:

```
SELECT
    dataAcesso,
    COUNT( idAcesso ) AS totalAcessos,
    COUNT( contato ) AS totalContatos,
    COUNT( IF(contato > 0, NULL, 1) ) AS semContato
FROM
    acessos
GROUP BY
    dataAcesso
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `COUNT` **não conta valores nulos**, é preciso fazer um tratamento:

```
SELECT
    dataAcesso,
    COUNT( idAcesso ) AS totalAcessos,
    COUNT( contato ) AS totalContatos,
    COUNT( NULLIF(contato, 1) ) AS semContato
FROM
    acessos
GROUP BY
    dataAcesso
```

Basicamente, o `NULLIF(contato, 1)` converte o null e 1, contato 1 para cada nulo

Comment: Dessa forma o `semContato` não retornará 0 visto que em caso negativo o valor retornado será o da primeira expressão que será `NULL`?

Comment: Não retornou 0, mas os valores ainda não batem `2019-09-28 | totalAcessos: 20 | totalContatos: 6 | semContato: 2`. Com isso já é possível fazer o que eu queria. O totalAcessos e totalContatos estão com os valores corretos então eu poderia simplesmente fazer `totalAcessos - totalContatos` para obter o semContato. Vou atualizar a pergunta com a tabela preenchida.

Comment: O NULLIF está retornando NULL quando o valor é 1, então acaba contando os contatos do formulario de id 2 quando deveria, na verdade, contar o total de NULL.